# Can't get value from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem when i try to get value of isBusy property from my database. A used breakpoints and it even doesn't go to instruction where i assign a value for isBusy, it assigns empty string and goes to else condition.

```
if docChild == 0 {
        let selectedDoctor = Doctors.doc1
        var isBusy = String()

        databaseHandle = reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.isBusy).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            isBusy = snapshot.value as! String
        })

        if isBusy == "false" {
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.isBusy).setValue("true")
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.firstname).setValue(firstNameLabel.text)
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.lastname).setValue(lastNameLabel.text)
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.pesel).setValue(peselLabel.text)
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.telephone).setValue(phoneLabel.text)


        } else {
            createAlert(title: "Przepraszamy - termin jest zajęty", message: "Proszę wybrać inny termin")

        }
```

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg89e.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is fairly simply. Firebase Database requests are asynchronous, so that at the time you reach your `if isBusy == "false"` statement the value did not get fetched from the Database. Change your code accordingly:

```
if docChild == 0 {
    let selectedDoctor = Doctors.doc1
    var isBusy = String()

    databaseHandle = reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.isBusy).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        isBusy = snapshot.value as! String
        if isBusy == "false" {
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.isBusy).setValue("true")
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.firstname).setValue(firstNameLabel.text)
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.lastname).setValue(lastNameLabel.text)
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.pesel).setValue(peselLabel.text)
            reference.child(selectedDoctor).child(dateChild).child(timeChild).child(ReservationFields.telephone).setValue(phoneLabel.text)


        } else {
            createAlert(title: "Przepraszamy - termin jest zajęty", message: "Proszę wybrać inny termin")

        }
   })
```

As you can see I simply moved your code **into** the handler, so it gets executed **after** your value has been fetched.

Comment: XCode told me to write self. in many places, now it doesn't go to instruction where i assign value to isBusy and next instructions.