# Method which returns all children of firebase node as Map Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, callback

I am trying to write a method which returns a map that should contain all children of a node in Firebase, but since I have to use callbacks the method returns an empty map.

```
public Map<Date, String> getChildrenAsMap(String nodeId) {
    DatabaseReference refernce= dbRoot.child("childName").child(nodeId);
    final Map<Date, String> childMap = new HashMap<>();

    refernce.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<Date, String> data = (Map<Date, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            for (Map.Entry<Date, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
                childMap .put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
    return childMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Firebase queries happen asynchronous and the listener gets called after you returned your map. To keep it simple: You cannot make an asynchronous method like this because the `ValueEventListener` already is an interface that does exactly this. If you wanted a method like this to work you'd need to create a class that handles it for you, but this is no need because you have everything you want provided by **Firebase for Android**:

```
DatabaseReference refernce= dbRoot.child("childName").child(nodeId);

deviceHistory.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<Date, String> childMap = new HashMap<>();

        Map<Date, String> data = (Map<Date, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        for (Map.Entry<Date, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            childMap.put(entry.getKey(), (String) entry.getValue());
        }

        // handle your childMap modifications in here, this gets executed after the value is retrieved
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w("TAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

I wrote another similar annotation (although for Swift, but that is not the relevant point) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516370/cant-get-value-from-firebase/46516456#46516456). You will just have to write your logic into the `ValueEventListener` everytime you want to use it. It already is a method, so you do not need to create a new one.